# how to close close_wait Statuc connections in netty spring cloud gateway

Tags: java, spring-boot, netty, reactor-netty

We are sping cloud gateway with netty on VSI servers. when we run the below linux command on lunux box ,it is showing large number of connections with status as CLOSE-WAIT

**please find the following metric and provide the solution for spring boot application **

Linux command :  ss -ta

State                  Recv-Q             Send-Q        Local Address:Port                                  PeerAddress:Por                        Process

CLOSE-WAIT             1                  0            xx.0.0.x:yyyyy                                         xx.0.0.x:yyyy
CLOSE-WAIT             1                  0            xx.0.0.x:yyyyy                                         xx.0.0.x:yyyy
CLOSE-WAIT             1                  0            xx.0.0.x:yyyyy                                         xx.0.0.x:yyyy
CLOSE-WAIT             1                  0            xx.0.0.x:yyyyy                                         xx.0.0.x:yyyy
CLOSE-WAIT             32                 0            xxx.xxx.x.xxx:yyyyy                                    xxx.xx.xx.xxx:https
ESTAB                  0                  551          xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:yyyyy                                   xxx.xx.xx.xxx:distinct